# Significance of sign of perturbation matrix

Tags: hamiltonian, perturbation-theory, matrix-elements

I understand that the off-diagonal elements of a Hamiltonian denote the interaction between different states. The magnitude of off-diagonal elements therefore tells us how strong the interaction is. But I don't know what role is played by the sign of the offidiagonal elements.

For example, consider this hamiltonian.

$$
H =
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
E_1&{-\triangle}\\
{-\triangle}&E_2\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

I can write this as

$$
H = H_0 - {\triangle}
$$

According to my knowledge, the energy of the eigen states of H will be slightly shifted than the energy of the unperturbed states ( $E_1$ and $E_2$ ) because of the off diagonal elements.

Does it mean that if I replace - signs in the H matrix by + signs, the energy shifts will have an opposite sign now?

EDIT: I tried calculating the new eigenvalues. The eigenvalues with + sign are the same as with - sign. The sign does NOT seem to have any effect on eigenvalues ( not in this particular example at least ).

Is it all, or is there some other change involved here which I am not aware of ?

Comment: Well, did you try to calculate the energy eigenvalues?

Comment: @Qmechanic , I tried calculating the eignevalues ( after reading your comment ). It seems that the perturbed eigenvalues are still the same ( unaffected by the change of sign). It makes me even more curious, what is the significance of sign then?

Comment: The eigenvalues are the same, but the eigenvectors are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the non-diagonal elements are complex numbers, i.e. they may have a phase:
\begin{equation}
\hat{H} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
E_1 & \Delta e^{i\phi}\\
\Delta e^{-i\phi} & E_2\\
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}
In your case the phase is $\phi = \pi$. From the point of view of the energy levels the phase is irrelevant, as they are determined in terms of the absolute value of the non-diagonal elements:
\begin{equation}
E_{\pm} = \frac{E_1 + E_2}{2} \pm \sqrt{\left(\frac{E_1 - E_2}{2}\right)^2 + |\Delta e^{i\phi}|^2}.
\end{equation}

This phase however allows for interpretation. For example, if this is a spin-1/2 Hamiltonian, it could be written as
\begin{equation}
\hat{H} = \frac{E_1 + E_2}{2} + \frac{E_1 - E_2}{2}\hat{\sigma}_z + \Delta\cos\phi \hat{\sigma}_x - \Delta\sin\phi\hat{\sigma}_y,
\end{equation}
where $\sigma_{x,y,z}$ are the Pauli matrices. The phase thus corresponds to the direction of the transversal component of the magnetic field.